# Sort value of hashmap

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have below `hashmap` like below:

```
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  map.put("a", 4);
  map.put("b", 9);
  map.put("c", 1);
```

I want to sort the hashmap based by their value, it should give output like :

```
[1, 4, 9]
```

Is this possible using Comparator?

UPDATE: Link provided does not provide the solution, I tried the solution, created hashmap cannot be traversed by key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Comment: HashMaps doesn't have order. You will need to store these values somewhere else.

Comment: @Pshemo It is big hashmap, is it fine to store somewhere else and then sort by value?

Comment: @ViniSoni check the link provided by SMA, I think you will get solution there, if not update here

Comment: As I said, HashMaps are unordered structures so you can't enforce any order on them. You need new structure which will store this values and order it later.

Comment: @SMA It is worth mentioning that top answer in that duplicate is terrible, and OP should not use it. There are better alternatives in other answers.

Comment: @SMA I tried the solution provided in duplicate link but created hashmap cannot be traversed by key.

Comment: @ViniSoni Paste your modified code.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `HashMap`? If you want it to be sorted by value, why do you need un-sorted access by key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java 8 solution that is collecting the stream in a `Map`:

```
   Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("a", 4);
    map.put("b", 9);
    map.put("c", 1);

    Map<String, Integer> orderedByValueMap =
            map.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (o1, o2) -> o1, LinkedHashMap::new));

    System.out.println(orderedByValueMap);
```

Output: `{c=1, a=4, b=9}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      map.put("a", 4);
      map.put("b", 9);
      map.put("c", 1);
      List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
      l.sort(null);
      System.out.println(l);
```

This code gives output as you needed.

Comment: how can I keep track of keys now?